# Can I create a list in a pre-existing list?

Tags: list, sharepoint-designer

I have created a subsite in the main site and this site is to allow employees to gather and fill out forms and data pertaning to projects and the like. I have tried using different sites to check if the layout would be what I need, but I believe I may have to create my own template.

The form indicates the project description and other items, then there is another part (seperate list) that ask for the project ID, Action to be taken, completion date so on and so forth.

We want the users to receive an email indicating if a task has been asigned or needs to be completed, but also we want these projects to roll up. I tried using a rollup from 'webpart', but I received an error message. First, I am just wanting to know is it possible to create a list within another list and keep these two seperate lists, but yet not, together? Please let me know if you have any further questions. I am using SharePoint 2010.

Thank You

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot create a list within a list, but you can create a lookup to another list.

This exists a column such that each item has a reference to another list.

Thus, you can have a task list with a lookup column to your list of projects.

In your rollup, you can group by this lookup column, and even filter by it, to show custom views.

Comment: could i rollup by ID, lets say these projects have separate id numbers....can i do that instead?

Comment: Yeah, you can decide which column (from the list you're looking up on) to display, and build a view filtered on that column. If you have a spare couple of lists in a test site you can try on, Create a column and have a play.

Comment: I have used a 'Decision Meeting Workspace'. This gives me 'Objectives', 'Agenda' and 'Attendees'. I believe I can go without the attendees, but will leave it in case it may be needed. I have taken the requirments from the sheet and transfered them to 'Objectives' (1st list) and did the same for 'Agenda' (2nd list). I would like to change the name Objectives and Agenda to something else. How can I do this? I checked in the 'List Settings', but it appears as though I will have to change the web address too, is this possible? (ites/honey/ProjectCharter/Lists/Objectives/AllItems.aspx)

Comment: Renaming lists is a sticky one, but is discussed here, both code and no-code ways of doing it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805005/how-to-rename-a-list-in-sharepoint

Comment: Yes, I can see it is a rather sticky situation. However, I found a like within the link you had sent me [http://www.thesharepointblog.net/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=815f255a%2Dd0ef%2D4258%2Dbe2a%2D28487dc9975c&ID=52] and it seems to work. The only issue I am finding is when I want to make modifcations to my page, then I have to go back into SPD and rename, the names, back and forth again, please view the article. What I plan to do at the moment before my next step is to create a template. I have 3 lists on this page and all are synced using ID's. Any other ideas or concerns I may need to know?

Comment: I went to create a template, but was given an error message.

Correlation ID: be52b12d-3bdc-4f3d-9c77-d12894232144

Comment: Did you get that error before or after you tried to rename it? I'd strongly recommend you try to save the template before you rename it. SharePoint is very funny about the URLs of things, especially lists, and it can misbehave very easily when these are changed.

Comment: I saved as template it after I renamed. Ok should I name it back to what it was? Then try to save a template? Because as soon as this template is saved, I can add it to an actual site (not a toy site).

Comment: I changed the URL back to the original and receive an error message when I want to save as template, this time.

Comment: Thank you James, I have re-created the site and now have a template. Also, I found it easier to change the navigation and title of my pages by going to List Settings --> Title, Description, and navigation. I'm only having one last snafu and before I ask the question, I have to figure out how to ask it. Thank you for your help. :)